# Compress folder using Powershell from SQLSERVER runtime

Tags: sqlps

I need to zip a folder using powershell from within SQLPS runtime. I tried the following from `PS SQLSERVER:\>` prompt:

```
$dest = "C:\SomePath\FolderToBeZipped"
$zipfile = $dest + ".zip"
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($dest,$zipfile)
```

When run, I get the below error :

> Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'system.io.compression.filesystem' could not be found.
>   At C:\SomePath\Compress.ps1:10 char:9
>   + Add-Type <<<<  -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (system.io.compression.filesystem:String) [Add-Type], Exception
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeComm

and

> Add-Type : Cannot add type. One or more required assemblies are missing.
>   At C:\SomePath\Compress.ps1:10 char:9
>   + Add-Type <<<<  -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_LOAD_ERRORS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

But if I exit out of `PS SQLSERVER:\>` runtime and execute from normal PS command prompt it is able to compress successfully. Please help how to compress from SQLSERVER powershell runtime. I even tried to invoke a separate .ps1 script (for compressing) using `Invoke-Expression` from within `PS SQLSERVER:\>` runtime, but failed. Please help